# Migration from Fuerte to Hydro

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, ros-hydro, serialization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on some code that I haven't made.
The thing is that I have to work in Hydro and this code was made for Fuerte.

I tried to catkinize the packages changing the manifest.xml and CMakeLists.txt
I don't know if it is needed to change anything else but when I try to make the package I get an error.

```
CMakeFiles/LLtoUTMsNode.dir/src/LLtoUTMsNode.cpp.o: In function `ros::serialization::Stream::advance(unsigned int)':
/home/summitxl/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/ros/serialization.h:721: undefined reference to ros::serialization::throwStreamOverrun()'
/home/summitxl/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/ros/serialization.h:721: undefined reference to `ros::serialization::throwStreamOverrun()'
/home/summitxl/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/ros/serialization.h:721: undefined reference to `ros::serialization::throwStreamOverrun()'
/home/summitxl/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/ros/serialization.h:721: undefined reference to `ros::serialization::throwStreamOverrun()'
/home/summitxl/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/ros/serialization.h:721: undefined reference to `ros::serialization::throwStreamOverrun()'
CMakeFiles/LLtoUTMsNode.dir/src/LLtoUTMsNode.cpp.o:/home/summitxl/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/ros/serialization.h:721: more undefined references to `ros::serialization::throwStreamOverrun()' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

make[2]: *** [/home/summitxl/catkin_ws/devel/lib/test_GPS/LLtoUTMsNode] Error 1

make[1]: *** [Ensayos/test_GPS/CMakeFiles/LLtoUTMsNode.dir/all] Error 2

make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/162776/migration-from-fuerte-to-hydro/) by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 223 on 2014-05-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You know that you don't have to catkinize your code to try it with Hydro? May it is better to first get the packages building using rosbuild (adapting them to potential API changes of dependencies) and after that consider to catkinize them.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4